# rclone confusing my bucket name with folder name?

Tags: php, rclone

I'm using laravel php artisan command to do a rclone copy of a sql database dump, however I'm getting the following error:

> Failed to copy: s3 upload: 404 Not Found:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error>
<Code>NoSuchBucket</Code>
<Message></Message>
<BucketName>sql-backups</BucketName>
<RequestId>txxxxxxxxx-0065f424e0-e72ab73d-fra1b</RequestId><HostId>xxxxx-fra1b-fra1-zgxx</HostId>
</Error>
```

Notice the message name says (I think) that no bucket named sql-backups was found, but sql-backups is the folder inside my bucket name called gabotron, both the bucket and the folder exist (as I can correctly ls their contents) but for some reason rclone is trying to look for a bucket name sql-backups

This is my code:

```
$remoteName = env('SPACES_BUCKET');
$bucketFoldername = 'sql-backups';
$datestring = date('Y_m_d_H');
$filename = "{$dirname}/{$database}-{$datestring}.sql.gz";

$configFile = "/home/Gabotron/configs/rclone/laraapp.conf";

        // Rclone command for copy
        $rcloneCopyCommand = "rclone --config={$configFile} copy {$filename} {$remoteName}:{$bucketFoldername}";

        $this->info($rcloneCopyCommand);
```

When I print on console `$rcloneCopyCommand` I get this (which seems about right).

```
rclone --config=/home/Gabotron/configs/rclone/laraapp.conf copy /home/Gabotron/sql-backups/laraapp-2024_03_15_10.sql.gz gabotron:sql-backups
```

Why is rclone trying to find a bucket that doesn't exist even when I'm specifying the bucket name correctly.

My config file (changed credentials):

```
[gabotron]
type = s3
env_auth = false
access_key_id = xxx
secret_access_key = xxxx/xxxx
endpoint = fra1.digitaloceanspaces.com
acl = public-read
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you narrow down "seems about right", does it actually work when run as the PHP user?

Comment: the command runs correctly but i get the error in OP